# Intuition behind time dilation and length contraction from relativity of simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, relativity, thought-experiment

I'm trying to build intuition behind time dilation and length contraction from the following experiment: [image]

*Image from "Fundamentals of Physics, 10th edition"*

Here, Sally's ship has velocity $v$ with respect to Sam's ship. Event Red and Event Blue leaves permanent marks on the ships. Bot Sam and Sally are standing at the midpoint of their respective ships.

As shown in the image, the wavefronts from both events reach Sam at the same moment and he determines them to be simultaneous. But since Sally herself is travelling towards the Red wavefront, it reaches her before the Blue wavefront.

Now, to justify the time dilation and length contraction, I interpreted it as this:
since Sally is travelling towards the Red wavefront, she will measure the wavefront to be coming towards her at a velocity $\dfrac{l}{2t}=c+v$, where $l$ is the length of he ship. But since the light postulate says the velocity of light is constant in all frames. Thus, to make the measured velocity equal to $c$, her measured time must dilate, or the length of the ship contract or both.
But if I consider the case for the Blue wavefront, it is exactly the opposite of what happens with the Red wavefront, which contradicts the previous interpretation.

So what is the proper way to think about time dilation and length contraction from this experiment? Can the equations of these phenomena be derived from this experiment, instead of the mirror-light experiment?

Comment: As someone who has seen these questions (and so many bad replies) over and over again hundreds of times on various forums, I can say with certainty that time dilation and length contraction really are _not_ intuitive concepts, and are not used to seriously address most problems in SR.  Actual real world problems are solved using the Spacetime Interval, the Lorentz Transform, and the Doppler Effect.  These are the things to learn.